# Using jscript / jquery in a div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I’m trying to use jscript/ jquery in a div but have been unsuccessful. For example, the code below is for file1.php, then file2.php  The datepicker on both files work independently, but when file2.php is brought into the div on file1.php, the datepicker from file2.php inside the div does not work. But the on native to file1.php does.  Any suggestions?

UPDATE!!! Found the solution. Here’s the code…

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../datepicker/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script type="text/jscript" src="../datepicker/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="../datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<script type="text/jscript">
function autoSubmit() {
$.post('file2.php', $('form[name="report"]').serialize(), function (output) {
$('#info').html(output).show();
$('#info').find('#datepicker2').datepicker();
});
}
</script>
<head>
<form name="report" action="submit.php" method="post">
<select name="Select1" onchange="autoSubmit();">
<option></option>
<option value="Value1">Value1</option>
<option value="Vaule2">Vaule2</option>
</select>
</form>
File 1 Date Picker<input name="Date" id="datepicker1" value="<?php echo date("n/j/Y");?>">
<div id="info"></div>
```

file2.php code.

```
File 2 Date Picker <input name="Date" id="datepicker2" value="<?php echo date("n/j/Y");?>">
```

Comment: Move all your scripts to the end of the file. And remove the `type` attribute from your script tags.

Comment: There's only one file here..

Comment: Maybe because of duplicate ids?

Comment: @bfavaretto: For general knowledge, why removing the `type` attributes?

Comment: note: if the datepicker in file2 is with id `datepicker1` then it is invalid because `id` should be unique in a document

Comment: @Itay, jscript is Microsoft.  Most browsers will throw it out.  HTML5 says not to use a type attribute for JavaScript, and every browser just assumes JavaScript (or jscript on IE) if there's no type attribute.

Comment: Oh thanks I haven't noticed it says JScript instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the contents of `file2` is loaded using a post command the widgets inside file2 has to be initialized after the dom is loaded with the content.

From what I understood you have an input field with id `datepicker1` in file1 and file2, it is invalid because element id should be unique in a document, I would recommend adding a class called `data-picker` to file2 input field. then try

```
function autoSubmit() {
    $.post('file2.php', $('form[name="report"]').serialize(), function (output) {
        $('#info').html(output).show();

        $('#info').find('.date-picker').datepicker();
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

if the following script is present in file2 then

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
```

you need to move the script to bottom of the page, ie after the input element is added and change the `id` to be a unique value

Comment: I believe that when jQuery `.html()` sees a script in the code, it executes it after updating the DOM with the rest of the HTML. So any initializations in the loaded script will be done at the proper time.

Comment: @Barmar I thought the script portion was not present in `file2`, then OP need to move the script to bottom of the page and then change the `id` to be a unique value because otherwise dom will always return the first element

Comment: He said that file2.php works by itself, so it must have the script portion as well. But you're right about making the IDs unique, several people already said that in comments.

Comment: I've edited the question to show page file1 & file2 with suggestions provided, still not working. Moving the code around seems to have no effect on the date pickers functionality.